# how to expand/collapse table rows using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to expand/collapse the following row if row with class='sector' is clicked

This same code seems to work for many people as per other stackoverflow answers but it is not working for me and I wonder why? I do not know much jquery but this seems to me to be workable but still does not work.

Kindly give a simple solution

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td[colspan=2]").hide();
  $("tr.sector").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td scope="col">Sector</th>
        <td scope="col">Total Qty</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sector">
      <td>Sector no. 2</td>
      <td>
        M : 1, </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p>
          <div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">Plot no. 5 | NPSC Apartment</div>
              <div class="col-4">1 Packets</div>
              <div class="col-4"><a href="/home/mark-deliveries?sector=&amp;plot=5">Details</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sector">
      <td>Sector no. 3</td>
      <td>
        M : 2, MJ : 1, </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p>
          <div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">Plot no. 1 | Heritage Tower (Sawan CGHS)</div>
              <div class="col-4">1 Packets</div>
              <div class="col-4"><a href="/home/mark-deliveries?sector=&amp;plot=1">Details</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">Plot no. 8 | Himachali Apartment</div>
              <div class="col-4">2 Packets</div>
              <div class="col-4"><a href="/home/mark-deliveries?sector=&amp;plot=8">Details</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you loading the jQuery library somewhere on your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hiding the `td[colspan=2]` inside `tr` and trying to toggle that same `tr` without actuality showing the `td` you have hidden in first place.

So you need to use `next` to get next `tr` sibling and find inside `td[colspan=2]` you have hidden and toggle that.

Please [read documentation on Jquery Tree Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) and next time watch for your HTML tree. Its all well documented and explained on link provided.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("tr > td[colspan=2]").hide();

  $("tr.sector").click(function() {
    $(this).next().find("td[colspan=2]").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td scope="col">Sector</th>
        <td scope="col">Total Qty</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sector">
      <td>Sector no. 2</td>
      <td>
        M : 1, </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p>
          <div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">Plot no. 5 | NPSC Apartment</div>
              <div class="col-4">1 Packets</div>
              <div class="col-4"><a href="/home/mark-deliveries?sector=&amp;plot=5">Details</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sector">
      <td>Sector no. 3</td>
      <td>
        M : 2, MJ : 1, </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <p>
          <div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">Plot no. 1 | Heritage Tower (Sawan CGHS)</div>
              <div class="col-4">1 Packets</div>
              <div class="col-4"><a href="/home/mark-deliveries?sector=&amp;plot=1">Details</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">Plot no. 8 | Himachali Apartment</div>
              <div class="col-4">2 Packets</div>
              <div class="col-4"><a href="/home/mark-deliveries?sector=&amp;plot=8">Details</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```